# Long-term effects of looking at restricted color gamuts

Tags: sensory-perception

Computer screens are [very bad](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/tests/picture-quality/color-gamut#:%7E:text=A%20monitor%27s%20color%20gamut%20describes,true%2Dto%2Dlife%20image.) at representing pure colors, in particular green (note the large uniformly green area on the charts that wouldn't be uniform if your screen could render highly saturated greens). In fact, this is one of the rare places where there is simply no high-tech replacement for [ink on cellulose](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1595127-REG/pantone_gg6104a_color_bridge_guide_uncoated.html?ap=y&smp=y&srsltid=AWLEVJwCS3owuNOn9UE9adLX5miIAKGdciesuo8FcGln8V6F2e2ljJi6FTs).

Given the enormous amount of time we spend on screens in this "post"-pandemic world, are there any studies on the long-term effects? It is probably most practical to have in interventional study by exposing people to a variety of "pure" colors and seeing if there are any mental-health or perception benefits to doing so.